# Acess Issue on Jira/Atlassian with R

Tags: r, jira

I got a Atlassian/Jira account where projects are listed on. I would like to import the various issues in order to make some extra analysis. I found a way to connect to Atlassian/Jira and to import what I want on Python:

```
    from jira import JIRA
    import os
    impot sys
    options = {'server': 'https://xxxxxxxx.atlassian.net'}
    jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('admin_email', 'admin_password'))
    issues_in_proj = jira.search_issues('project=project_ID')
```

It works very well but I would like to make the same thing in R. Is it possible ? I found the RJIRA package but there are three problems for me:

1. It's still on a dev version
2. I am unable to install it as the DESCRIPTION file is "malformed".
3. It's based on a jira server URL: "https://JIRAServer:port/rest/api/" and I have a xxxxx.atlassian.net URL

I also found out that there are curl queries :

```
    curl -u username:password -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
    "http://jiraServer/rest/api/2/search?jql=created%20>%3D%202015-11-18"
```

but again it is based on a "https://JIRAServer:port/rest/api/" form and in addition I am using windows.

Do someone have an idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "https://JIRAServer:port/rest/api/" form is the Jira REST API https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

As a rest api, it just makes http method calls and gives you data.

All jira instances should expose the rest api, just point your browser to your jira domain like this:

https://xxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/field

and you will see all the fields you have access to, for example

This means you can use php, java or a simple curl call from linux to get your jira data. I have not used RJIRA but if you dont want to use it, you can still use R (which I have not used) and make an HTTP call to the rest api.

These two links on my blog might give you more insight:

http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/06/rest-api-calls-with-resttemplate.html
http://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/05/jira-confluence-3.html

Good luck :)